# "Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin" when using createDrawerNavigator()

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, react-navigation

I get this error

> Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 change listeners added to [HasteMap]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

> ERROR    Error: Requiring module "node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/src/index.tsx", which threw an exception: Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

With this code

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

I am using

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.4",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
```

Why is it throwing the error?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?